# Nodejs : readline interface don't prompt question

Tags: node.js, readline

I'm new to node so please help me,
i just try to make a little program who ask a question, take the answer of user and back him an information relatead with .
there is my piece of code :

```
//Rendre un programme node console interactif
var readline = require('readline')
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  outpout: process.stdout
})

rl.question(`Quel est votre nom ?`, (nom) => {
  console.log(`Akwaba ${nom}!`)
  rl.close()
})
```

when i run this there is no question display but program wait directly for an input from user.
I'm doing something bad

Comment: `outpout: process.stdout` looks like a typo.

Comment: @WiktorZychla , thak you , shame on me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

outpout: process.stdout looks like a typo. –
Wiktor Zychla
Jan 4, 2021 at 11:50